# How can I print contents of file given filename as stdin in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a bash command like `cat` except that it takes the filename from stdin rather than the first argument?  For example:

```
echo "/home/root/file.txt" | somecommand
```

would have the same output as `cat /home/root/file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
xargs cat
```

For example:

```
echo "/home/root/file.txt" | xargs cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filename that you're expecting doesn't have a space:

```
#!/bin/bash    
read filename
cat $filename
```

The read builtin shell command reads tokens from stdin into environment variables.